# Is there a way to serverlessly update a big aggregated table daily?

Tags: python, firebase, google-bigquery

I am trying to build a big aggregated table with googles tools but I am a bit lost on the 'how to do it'.

Here is what I would like to create: I have a big table in bigquery. Its updated daily with about 1.2M events for evert user of the application. I would like to have an auto updating aggregate table(udpated once every day) built upon that with all user data broken by userID. But how do I continiously update the data inside of it?

I read a bit about firebase and bigquery but since they are very new to me I cant figure out if this is possible to do serverlessly?

I know how to do it with a jenkins process that queries the big events table for the last day, gets all userIDs, joins with the data from the existing aggregate values for the userIDs, takes whatever is changed and deletes from the aggregate in order to insert the updated data. (In python)

The issue is I want to do this entirely within the structure of google. Is firebase able to do that? Is bigquery able? How? What tools? Could this be solved using the serverless functions available?

I am more familiar with Redshift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pretty new BigQuery feature that to [schedule queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries).
I use it to create rollup tables. If you need more custom stuff you can use [cloud scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) to call any Google product that can be triggered by an [HTTP request](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/http-target-auth) such as cloud function, cloud run, or app engine.

Comment: Yep that will help a lot. Thanks.